# Azure DevOps: Approver unable to approve their own PR

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

This is the current branch policy

[image]

and there are required approvers also. The problem is when the required approver creates his own PR, Azure dev-Ops disallows and shows that one of the approvers need to approve the PR.

How can we allow the required approvers to approve their own PR

Comment: can you share the screenshot from the required reviewers section?

Comment: hmm sorry, I'm not allowed to do that :)   but there are some.

Comment: there is also a checkbox to check for  approve their own PR, is it checked?

Comment: as you can see, yes it is

Comment: @SimpleFellow - There are two separate policies.  One is minimum number of reviewers and one with required approvers.  They both have their own checkbox for allowing self-approval.  As you have not shared the reviewers configuration, we actually can not see it.   Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-157-update#granularity-for-automatic-reviewers) of the setting

Comment: @Matt Wow, they hid it very well. I've fallen for this one too!
Why they had to bury it in that sub menu (3 dots next to required reviewers) instead of putting it straightforward in the interface it's a mistery.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the response of Matt in the comments, you find it here:

[image]

Then go here

[image]

After changing these settings you can approve your own PRs as a required reviewer.